# How to search with each starting letter of words in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to get search results if my string is "customer details" .I am able to do a search if I type cust will get desired output but if I search using data keyword. I am getting no results. How to achieve with sequelize?

What I have tried -

```
sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('name')), 'LIKE', queryObj.keyword.toLowerCase() + '\%')
```

Generated Query

```
SELECT "Campaign"."id" FROM "Campaigns" AS "Campaign" LEFT OUTER JOIN "EmailCampaigns" AS "EmailCampaigns" ON "Campaign"."id" = "EmailCampaigns"."campaignId" AND ("EmailCampaigns"."deletedAt" IS NULL)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "CampaignEmailTemplates" AS "CampaignEmailTemplate" ON "Campaign"."id" = "CampaignEmailTemplate"."campaignId" 
 AND ("CampaignEmailTemplate"."deletedAt" IS NULL) 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "CampaignScheduleRequests" AS "CampaignScheduleRequest" ON "Campaign"."id" = "CampaignScheduleRequest"."campaignId" 
 AND ("CampaignScheduleRequest"."deletedAt" IS NULL) 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "CampaignStats" AS "CampaignStat" ON "Campaign"."id" = "CampaignStat"."campaignId"  AND ("CampaignStat"."deletedAt" IS NULL) 
 WHERE ("Campaign"."deletedAt" IS NULL AND ("Campaign"."accountId" = 403 
AND LOWER("Campaign"."name") iLIKE 'cust%')) ORDER BY "Campaign"."updatedAt" DESC;
```

Comment: Please show the generated SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way can be achieved by

```
sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('name')), {[Op.iRegexp]: `\\y${queryObj.keyword.toLowerCase()}.*\\y`})
```

Comment: See my previous answer. I always try to avoid regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('name')), {[Op.like]: `%${queryObj.keyword.toLowerCase()}%`}),
```

Comment: it will search on only first word from  name column .How to do  with every word

Comment: This is not only the first word. It will search from starting. Suppose your name is Priyanka Bondarde. When you search for pri, it where clause will search like this way, "pri%". That means everything that will start with pri will be your output.

Comment: If you search all over the text, you can use  `%${queryObj.keyword.toLowerCase()}%` it will search if your keyword is present anywhere in the text. Hope you will understand

Comment: Yes, I understood, but I want to develop something like if I search for Bond it should give me the result of Priyanka Bondarde . I don't want in-between characters to be searched

Comment: Ok. I got it. Check the answer. I have modified my answer. Hope this will work for you.